# Javascript add integers to mixed array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create some synthetic data which needs to be represented in this kind of structure (an array of arrays):

```
dataset = [
  ['Period', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'],
  ['2018-01', 2000, 2002, 2004],
  ['2018-08', 3000, 3003, 3006],
  ['2019-01', 4000, 4002, 4008]
]
```

I've made a function to help:

```
function get_datapoints() {
    dates = ['2018-01', '2018-08', '2019-01']

    data = [];
    data.push(['Period', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'])

    for (i in dates) {
        sequence = []
        for (val = 1; val < 4; val++) {
            sequence.push(get_randomval())
        }
        data.push([dates[i], sequence.join()])
        console.log(data)
    }
    return data

function get_randomval(min = 2000, max = 5000) {
    let difference = max - min;
    let rand = Math.random();
    rand = Math.floor(rand * difference);
    rand = rand + min;
    return parseInt(rand);
}
```

This is generating data which looks like this:

```
[
  ['Period', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']
  ['2018-01', '59797,47895,63209']
  ['2018-08', '28342,38450,70694']
  ['2019-01', '32348,44872,92501']
]
```

This understandably gives the error:
Error: Row 1 has 2 columns, but must have 4

Clearly there are two 'fields' in each data array, each enclosed in a single quote pair. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to get those integers into the array without the single quotes. This data is actually to be used as part of a google.visualization.arrayToDataTable needed by Google Charts.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart
shows an example of this kind of structure (an array with both strings and ints).

How can I get those values into their arrays without the single quotes? Thanks!

Comment: Use `data.push([dates[i], ...sequence])` instead of `data.push([dates[i], sequence.join()])`

Comment: `join` turns your array into a string.

Comment: Fantastic! All working now! Spread operator huh? Thats a new one to me.

Comment: You definitely should be declaring your variables with `let` or `const`, as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, yes, I'm slowly getting back up to speed with Js now and appreciate the observation and suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `sequence.join()` This method is used for strings and when no arguments are provided it converts the elements in the array to a string with a `,` as delimiter. That's why you get the string.

You could use the spread operator instead, this will behave as you inteded to.

```js
data.push([dates[i], ...sequence])
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using join here `data.push([dates[i], sequence.join()])` (which converts it to a string) use the spread operator like this `data.push([dates[i], ...sequence])`.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly converting to a string using `sequence.join`. You should instead pass each `sequence` item as a separate argument. I see answers suggesting the nifty unpacking operator:

```
[dates[i], ...sequence]
```

but there are older solutions which may be more readable such as

```
data.push([dates[i]].concat(sequence))
```

or using `unshift` to prepend `dates[i]` (costs an extra line), or **my favorite, just initialize the sequence like you want it**:

```
sequence = [dates[i]]
```

leave the code as is, and then just

```
data.push(sequence)
```

Comment: Thanks you @kabanus this makes a lot of sense. I like simple!